# Using view with separate thread than UI thread.

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, view

I have my own view which i draw a few bitmaps in the onDraw() function but this slows down getting touch events(miss some of them) that is why i want to separate drawing Bitmaps' thread and getting touch events' thread(UI Thread) but i don't know how because they both seems to must be in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go look at the sample applications that google provides as part of the SDK.  They give detailed examples of how to do stuff like this.

I would start with LunarLander.